# Getting user profiles from Slack Workspace with Slack API and Next.js

Tags: next.js, slack-api, userid

I consider myself somewhat affluent in Next.js and I mostly understand using APIs. But I'm still kind of a beginner. I’m trying to get a list of user profiles/ids from a slack workspace and store them in a database so I can create automatic accounts on a different website I’m developing.

The problem I ran into is that slack doesn't allow you to create tokens any more. See: https://api.slack.com/legacy/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens. That would make it a lot easier. I'm mainly trying to see if there is another way I can accomplish this.